# Ajax request (in WordPress) returns data in some version of Chrome but others and safari are just returning 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin that uses AJAX to pull data from the database and load it in the DOM:

jQuery:

```
jQuery.post(myAjax.ajaxurl,{action:'getNextSet',offset:offset},function(data){

    console.log(data);
    ...doing stuff with the data... 

},'json');
```

php:

```
function getNextSet() {
    global $wpdb;
    $playerTable = ...;
    $coachTable = ...;

    $offset = $_POST['offset'];
    $jsonArray = array();

    ... grab table data and store it to the array ...

    echo json_encode($jsonArray);
    die();
}
```

As you can see in my jQuery I'm running a `console.log` to test my data to make sure I'm getting back what I expect.

On my machine (mac) chrome spits out the data; on my machine with safari, I get "0". I tested it out on another machine (also a mac), chrome and safari both spit out a "0"

Comment: does php always return the same?

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: *shot-in-the-dark*, try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json')` before you echo the json.

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.10. Not sure what you mean by "does php always return the same?" In my chrome it works everytime. In my safari and chrome/safari on the other machine it never works.

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json')` had no affect

Comment: figured it out... it was a stupid wordpress mistake I was making